# when button is clicked many times, application becomes un-responsive

Tags: java, android, jakarta-ee, android-button, android-networking

I'm working on a android application in which one button is there which is used for fetching data from server and show into `TextView`, 
but the problem is, **if a user is clicking many times on a same button the application becomes un-responsive** in Android.

Comment: where is your code & LogCat outputs

Comment: What does Logcat show?

Comment: Are you using AsyncTask to get data from server?

Comment: What about utilizing the **art of programming** to fetch data asynchronously and only when required?

Comment: no i am not using asyncTask  and un-responsive means no logcat @PM77-1

Comment: Then try using AsyncTask. It may solve your problem. When sending and receiving data from server at a time the app may become un-responsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if a user is clicking many times on a same button the application
>   becomes un-responsive in Android

To avoid application becomes un-responsive on Button click:

**1.** Show ProgressBar on Button click and dissmiss it after getting response from server.

**2.** Use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for getting data from server in background Thread because if we put network related code on main thread then app will becomes un-responsive until response is not return from server

**3.**  Also handle button click when server request is already in progress by showing proper message like "In progress...".

Use a boolean varaible for handling click event :

```
boolean isTaskRunning=false;
```

on button click before starting `AsyncTask` check `isTaskRunning` status:

```
   if(!isTaskRunning){
       isTaskRunning=true;
       // start task for getting data from server

    }else{
         //... In progress...
    }
```

After getting data from server make `isTaskRunning` variable to `false`

Comment: but the problem is how do i get data, because Async task is returning null.

Comment: @Rah: Dear in question you are saying when user clicking multiple times app becomes un-responsive and i have answer according to your question now you are making question answer meaning less.

Comment: @Rah: this is not right way to ask question by appending new questions in comments if you have another question next time please make a new question instead of updating current question

Comment: @Rah: ok I am assuming you are getting response from server in `doInBackground` ? so are you getting response from server or not? if not then share related part of code to get more help from us

Comment: @Rah: Are you getting response from server or not in doInBackground?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). It may solve your problem. When sending and receiving data from server at a time the app may become un-responsive.

Answer (score 0):

How you are fetching data from server. If you are using Thread or AsyncTask then it is good. When user click on your button disable your button and then start thread or AsyncTask to fetch data from server. Once data is received populate it into textview and enable the button.

```
//disable click event
b.setClickable(false);

// enable click event
b.setClickable(true);
```

If you are fetching data on Main thread then your app may become unresponsive and throw ANR.